# extract title tag from html

Tags: html, tags, extract, title

I want to extract contents of title tag from html string. I have done some search but so far i am not able to find such code in VB/C# or PHP. Also this should work with both upper and lower case tags e.g. should work with both `<title></title>` and <`TITLE></TITLE>`. Thank you.

Comment: HTML is not, in general, well formed. Therefore any solution will come with error cases.

What error cases are acceptable to you?

Comment: I think it should ignore case and missing title tag from document. Maybe in best way it should be a function that return string title value or empty string if there is error or title tag is missing.

Answer (score 7):

You can use regular expressions for this but it's not completely error-proof. It'll do if you just want something simple though (in PHP):

```
function get_title($html) {
  return preg_match('!<title>(.*?)</title>!i', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
}
```

Comment: Looks like this function is case sensitive, this function does not extract title if its in upper case, can you alter this function to ignore the case?

Comment: The 'i' flag after the pattern makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for a regular expression.  This will depend on the HTML being well-formed, i.e., only finds the title element inside a head element.

```
 Regex regex = new Regex( ".*<head>.*<title>(.*)</title>.*</head>.*",
                          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
 Match match = regex.Match( html );
 string title = match.Groups[0].Value;
```

I don't have my regex cheat sheet in front of me so it may need a little tweaking.  Note that there is also no error checking in the case where no title element exists.

Comment: "Sounds like a job for ... The More-Than-Regular Expressor!" A developer by day, a superhero by night ;)

Comment: RE: "Well-formed" -- You're not required to place the `<title>` element as a child of `<head>` in HTML 4.01. I only point this out as an example of why using regex & HTML generally leads to frustration. See: http://shawn.medero.net/demos/valid-html4/

Comment: Even worse than soypunk correctly points out, there are many usable HTML files with a title that are not valid. e.g. <tiTlE>a<boDy>b You really need to use an HTML parser if you're going to handle real-world HTML.

Comment: So can any one suggest how to use an HTML parser to extract title?

Answer (score 0):

If there is any attribute in the title tag (which is unlikely but can happen) you need to update the expression as follows:

```
$title = preg_match('!<title.*>(.*?)</title>!i', $url_content, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
```