# how to extract a url's title, images, keywords and description using php?

Tags: php, url, extract, digg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to retrieve a <title> in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399332/fastest-way-to-retrieve-a-title-in-php)

Suppose there is a website http://www.example.com with title = "Example" description = "it is an example" and keywords = "example, question, love php".

What will be the php code or any other code with which these can be fetched on submission of the link?

Comment: You can get the title like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717100/extract-title-tag-from-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to fetch the data from an external link you want to get the page using curl.

Here's an example

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.google.nl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$title = preg_match('!<title>(.*?)</title>!i', $result, $matches) ? $matches[1] : 'No title found';
$description = preg_match('!<meta name="description" content="(.*?)">!i', $result, $matches) ? $matches[1] : 'No meta description found';
$keywords = preg_match('!<meta name="keywords" content="(.*?)">!i', $result, $matches) ? $matches[1] : 'No meta keywords found';

echo $title . '<br>';
echo $description . '<br>';
echo $keywords . '<br>';
?>
```

For google.nl this returns:

> ```
> Google
> No meta description found
> No meta keywords found
> ```

The meta description and keywords might need more tweaking for your use.

Little sidenote cURL is not installed by default in apache so you might need to install if first.

Here's the cURL php function page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general but the tool you will want is file_get_contents to get the page and then regex to find the data.  You could use this to find the title easily but what exactly you mean by keywords and description are unclear...

Comment: he meant the html headers.. and for heaven's sake, don't use regex..